# Incomplete package documentation in TeXLive 2012 on Ubuntu

Tags: packages, texlive, mactex, documentation

I use `MacTex 2012` on my laptop. On the desktop in our lab, I use `TeXLive 2012` on Ubuntu 12.04. I noticed that some package documentations in Ubuntu are not as comprehensive as they are in Mac.

To give you an example, `texdoc tikz` in my Mac brings up more than 700 pages of documentation, however, in my Linux machine `tikz` documentation is nowhere near that complete. I tried to update everything but I failed to update the documentation.

Why is there this problem and how to update all package documentation?

#### Edit

I checked the Ubuntu machine an realized that `texdoc tikz` opens the `tikz-3dplot` package documentation (latest version though). So the problem after all, *might* not be the outdated documentation but wrong entries for `texdoc`. Any ideas?

Comment: on the first page of the Tikz manual is the version. Does it match? How did you tried to updated everything?

Comment: @someonr, I can't answer your question about the version since I don't have access to that machine. Regarding the update, I used ubuntu's default package manager `apt-get`. TexLive itself was installed from official backports ppa and to my knowledge it was up to the latest version at the time.

Comment: Ubuntu is based on Debian. Debian has stricter requirements for file inclusion than does TeX Live, on which MacTeX is based. So both code and documentation must meet Debian's stricter guidelines for what counts as free software. In general, this is no different (or very little different) from TeX Live for programmes, macros etc. but the differences are more significant when it comes to documentation. In particular, the source of documentation must be included with no exceptions for Debian whereas things are a little less strict for TeX Live itself. Note I don't know how current this is though.

Comment: @Pouya, exactly how is TeXLive installed on that Ubuntu 12.04. AFAIK, the version you get from `apt-get` is not TL12 but TL09!

Comment: @daleif, as I mentioned above, I uninstalled the old version that comes with 12.04 and used the [official backport ppa](http://askubuntu.com/a/163683/103884). I installed texlive 2012 with -full option.

Comment: To check what documentation is being used, try `texdoc -l tikz`.  The `-l` switch (or `--list`) shows a list of possible matches, which you can then select from.  When I do that (on vanilla TL2013), the first option (of 22) on my list is `pgfmanual.pdf`, while the third is `tikz-3dplot_documentation.pdf`.

Comment: Is there any news here?